# VBA to click next page button with no unique identifiers

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

The portion of code pasted below attempts to loop through each page of a web search.  The button to do so is defined by the html also below.  The loop works through only the second page, regardless of the results page count, at which point, I receive a Permission denied (Error 70).

```
Sub finrascrape()

Dim ie As Object
Dim pgcount, a, i, commaindex As Integer
Dim bname, cc, cnum, pg, nb As IHTMLElement
Dim blist, clist, pagelist, nextb, testtxt, testtxt2 As IHTMLElementCollection

Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
brokersearch = InputBox("ENTER BROKER NAME OR CRD#")
firmsearch = InputBox("ENTER FIRM NAME OR CRD#")
geosearch = InputBox("ENTER ZIP CODE (must be valid zip code, otherwise leave blank)")

With ie
.navigate "https://brokercheck.finra.org/"
.Visible = True
Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
DoEvents
Loop
End With

Set intags = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("input")

For Each gat In intags
If gat.placeholder = "Name or CRD#" Then
gat.Value = brokersearch
Set evt = ie.document.createEvent("keyboardevent")
evt.initEvent "change", True, False
gat.dispatchEvent evt
ElseIf gat.placeholder = "Firm Name or CRD# (optional)" Then
gat.Value = firmsearch
Set evt = ie.document.createEvent("keyboardevent")
evt.initEvent "change", True, False
gat.dispatchEvent evt
ElseIf gat.placeholder = "City, State or Zip (optional)" Then
gat.Value = geosearch
Set evt = ie.document.createEvent("keyboardevent")
evt.initEvent "change", True, False
gat.dispatchEvent evt
Else
End If
Next gat

ie.document.getElementsByClassName("md-raised md-primary md-hue-2 md-button md-ink-ripple").Item.Click

Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> 4
DoEvents
Loop

Set pagelist = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("bold font-dark-blue ng-binding")

For Each pg In pagelist
If pg.className = "bold font-dark-blue ng-binding" Then
a = pg.innerText
Exit For
Debug.Print a
End If
Next pg

pgcount = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(a / 12, 0)
Debug.Print pgcount

Sheets("Results").Select
Range("A1").Value = "BROKER NAME"
Range("B1").Value = "BROKER CRD#"
Range("C1").Value = "MAILING CITY"
Range("D1").Value = "MAILING STATE"
Range("E1").Value = "MAILING ZIP"
With Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column))
    .Font.Bold = True
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
End With

For i = 1 To pgcount

On Error GoTo reportcomplete

Set blist = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("smaller ng-binding flex")

For Each bname In blist
Sheets("Results").Select
Sheets("Results").Range("A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = bname.innerText
Next bname

Set clist = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("smaller")

For Each cnum In clist
Sheets("Process").Select
If cnum.className = "smaller" Then
Sheets("Process").Range("A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = cnum.innerText
End If
Next cnum

Sheets("Process").Select
For a = 1 To Sheets("Process").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
If Left(Sheets("Process").Range("A" & a).Value, 4) = "CRD#" Then
Sheets("Results").Select
Sheets("Results").Range("B" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = Right(Sheets("Process").Range("A" & a).Value, Len(Sheets("Process").Range("A" & a)) - 7)
If InStr(Sheets("Process").Range("A" & a + 1).Value, ",") = 0 Then
Sheets("Process").Range("A" & a + 1).Value = "UNAVAILABLE, NA XXXXX"
End If
ElseIf InStr(Sheets("Process").Range("A" & a).Value, ",") > 0 Then
commaindex = InStr(Sheets("Process").Range("A" & a).Value, ",")
Sheets("Results").Select
Sheets("Results").Range("C" & Sheets("Results").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = Left(Sheets("Process").Range("A" & a).Value, commaindex - 1)
Sheets("Results").Range("D" & Sheets("Results").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = Left(Right(Sheets("Process").Range("A" & a).Value, _
Len(Sheets("Process").Range("A" & a)) - commaindex - 1), 2)
Sheets("Results").Range("E" & Sheets("Results").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = Left(Right(Sheets("Process").Range("A" & a).Value, _
Len(Sheets("Process").Range("A" & a)) - commaindex - 4), 5)
Else
End If
Sheets("Process").Select
Next a
Sheets("Process").Cells.Clear

Set testtxt = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a")

For Each txt In testtxt
If txt.className = "ng-binding" Then
txt.Click
Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> 4
DoEvents
Loop
Set testtxt2 = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
For a = pgcount To 2 Step -1
For Each txt2 In testtxt2
If txt2.className = "ng-binding" And txt2.innerText = a & " of " & pgcount & " pages" Then
'Debug.Print a
GoTo end_of_for
End If
Next txt2
Next a
End If
Next txt

end_of_for:

a = pgcount

Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> 4
DoEvents
Loop

Next i

reportcomplete:
MsgBox "FINRA Web Scrape Complete.  Please review."

End Sub
```

HTML:

```
<li ng-if="::directionLinks" ng-class="{disabled: noNext()||ngDisabled}" class="pagination-next ng-scope">
<a href="" ng-click="selectPage(page + 1, $event)" class="ng-binding">›</a></li>
```

The URL for the search landing page is https://brokercheck.finra.org.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that you have the proper rights to view/edit the page it's getting stuck on?

Comment: I certainly have the rights to view the page, as does the general public.  I do not have the rights to edit the page.  However, I do not believe that is necessary.  I simply want to click a button on the page, which I can on the first results page, but beyond that, I cannot.

Comment: Provide a demo search so that I can take a look.

Comment: For example, I would navigate to https://brokercheck.finra.org/ and enter "Michael John" as the individual's name and "Morgan Stanley" as the firm name, which yields 315 results across 27 pages.  The code will pull data from the first results page, click the next page button, pull data from the second page, then redirect to the landing page, https://brokercheck.finra.org/, and render a Permission Denied Error 70 message.  I have edited the code above to include the full script.

Answer (score 0):

I developed a loop as follows, which successfully navigates the "a" tagged elements, identifies the correct button based on the innerText of the prior element, and loops through each page.

```
Set testtxt = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a")

If i < pgcount Then
For d = 1 To testtxt.Length
If testtxt.Item(d).innerText = i & " of " & pgcount & " pages" Then
testtxt.Item(d + 1).Click
Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> 4
DoEvents
Loop
Exit For
End If
Next d
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can do to traverse all 27 pages and get the broker names.

```
Sub Get_Content()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer, html As HTMLDocument
    Dim itm As Object, post As Object, posts As Object, elem As Object

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://brokercheck.finra.org/"
        Do Until .readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: Loop
        Set html = .document
    End With

    Set evt = html.createEvent("keyboardevent")
    evt.initEvent "change", True, False

    For Each itm In html.getElementsByTagName("input")
        If InStr(itm.placeholder, "Name or CRD#") > 0 Then
            itm.Value = "Michael John"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next itm
    itm.dispatchEvent evt

    For Each post In html.getElementsByTagName("input")
        If InStr(post.placeholder, "Firm Name or CRD# (optional)") > 0 Then
            post.Value = "Morgan Stanley"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next post
    post.dispatchEvent evt

    html.getElementsByClassName("md-button")(0).Click
    Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    Do
        For Each elem In html.getElementsByClassName("smaller ng-binding flex")
            x = x + 1: Cells(x, 1) = elem.innerText
        Next elem

        html.getElementsByClassName("pagination-next")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).Click
        Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    Loop Until InStr(html.body.innerHTML, " class=""pagination-last ng-scope disabled""") > 0
    ie.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: See the edited code. It does everything successfully.